# Defining three related variables at the same time

Tags: python, variables

Essentially i need to derive a volume from area and depth (obviously). I'm a beginner so not sure what to do here.

so my problem is:

```
depth = volume / area

volume = area * depth

area = volume / depth
```

how can i define each of these at the same time, so that i don't get an 'undefined' message?

Many thanks

Comment: What's the starting point, i.e. which of these do you know a priori?

Comment: You have one equation and 3 unknowns, of course you will have issues defining the above trifecta.

Answer (score 6):

> I need to derive a volume from area and depth

Area and depth are *inputs,* so don't define them in terms of the other two variables.

```
def calculate_volume(area, depth):
    return area*depth
```